# Sending buffer via Boost ASIO server - sending the wrong data

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, server, boost-asio

Can anyone tell me how to send hexadecimal values stored in array unchanged to client??

whenever I send a char array of hexadecimal to client via boost server, its converting it to ASCII/JUNK(Can't decide what it is).

**for Ex:**

I am trying to send

```
"24 bb ff 0f 02 08 01 e0 01 e0 02 08 0f 2d 0f 00 23 61"
```

in char array via Boost asio server.

**Edit:**

Client is receiving

```
"32 34 62 62 66 66 30 66 30 32 30 38 30 31 65 30 30 31 65 30 30 32 30 38 30 66 32 64 30 66 30 30 32 33 36 31"
```

this is the piece of code I am using.

```
char Sendingdata_[512];
string finalHex = "24bbff0f020801e001e002080f2d0f002361";
strcpy(Sendingdata_, finalHex.c_str());
boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(Sendingdata_,bytes_transferred), boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

should I use different buffers or any other way to send hexadecimal values???

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and show sourcecode for sending.

Comment: Fixing the endianness, you're receiving "BAADF00D BAADF00D BAADF00D ...", so there's a bug in either end but it's impossible to guess where.

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as "hex values" - there's hexadecimal *representation* of values, but the number ten is the same regardless of whether you write it `10`, `0xa`, or `012`. The string `"10"` represents the array `{49, 48, 0}`, though.

Comment: You should have included code. We're not psychics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is attempting to send more than 37 bytes, then it will be sending uninitialized memory.  If it is attempting to send more than 512 bytes, then it is reading beyond the end of the buffer.  In either case, memory trash patterns may be sent.

The `Sendingdata_` buffer is 512 bytes, but only 37 of those bytes have been initialized.

```cpp
char Sendingdata_[512];                 // 512 unitialized values.
std::string finalHex = string-literal;  // 36 ASCII characters + null termination.
strcpy(Sendingdata_, finalHex.c_str()); // 37 characters copied
boost::asio::async_write(..., boost::asio::buffer(Sendingdata_, bytes_transferred), ...);
```

---

The `finalHex` string is being provided a string literal.  For example, assigning a string the string-literial of `"2400bb"`, will store the `'2'`, `'4'`, `'0'`, `'0'`, `'b'`, and `'b'` ASCII characters.

```cpp
std::string ascii = "2400bb";
assert(ascii.length() == 6);
assert('2' == ascii[0]);
assert('4' == ascii[1]);
assert('0' == ascii[2]);
assert('0' == ascii[3]);
assert('b' == ascii[4]);
assert('b' == ascii[5]);
```

Consider using a vector, providing the numeric value in hex notation:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned char> hex = { 0x24, 0x00, 0xbb };
assert(hex.size() == 3);
assert(0x24 == hex[0]);
assert(0x00 == hex[1]);
assert(0xbb == hex[2]);
```

Alternatively, one could use `std::string` by providing the `\x` control character to indicate that the subsequent value is hex.  However, one may need to perform explicit casting when interpreting the values, and use constructors that handle the null character within the string:

```cpp
std::string hex("\x24\x00\xbb", 3);
// alternatively: std::string hex{ 0x24, 0x00, static_cast<char>(0xbb) };  
assert(hex.size() == 3);
assert(0x24 == static_cast<unsigned char>(hex[0]));
assert(0x00 == static_cast<unsigned char>(hex[1]));
assert(0xbb == static_cast<unsigned char>(hex[2]));
```

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dce5d61603f686b8) the differences and Asio buffer usage:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  // String-literial.
  std::string ascii = "2400bb";
  assert(ascii.length() == 6);
  assert('2' == ascii[0]);
  assert('4' == ascii[1]);
  assert('0' == ascii[2]);
  assert('0' == ascii[3]);
  assert('b' == ascii[4]);
  assert('b' == ascii[5]);

  // Verify asio buffers.
  auto ascii_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(ascii);
  assert(ascii.length() == boost::asio::buffer_size(ascii_buffer));
  assert(std::equal(
    boost::asio::buffers_begin(ascii_buffer),
    boost::asio::buffers_end(ascii_buffer),
    std::begin(ascii)));

  // Hex values.
  std::vector<unsigned char> hex = { 0x24, 0x00, 0xbb };
  // alternatively: unsigned char hex[] = { 0x24, 0x00, 0xbb };
  assert(hex.size() == 3);
  assert(0x24 == hex[0]);
  assert(0x00 == hex[1]);
  assert(0xbb == hex[2]);

  // Verify asio buffers.
  auto hex_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(hex);
  assert(hex.size() == boost::asio::buffer_size(hex_buffer));
  assert(std::equal(
    boost::asio::buffers_begin(hex_buffer),
    boost::asio::buffers_end(hex_buffer),
    std::begin(hex),
    std::equal_to<unsigned char>()));

  // String with hex.  As 0x00 is in the string, the string(char*) constructor
  // cannot be used.
  std::string hex2("\x24\x00\xbb", 3);
  // alternatively: std::string hex2{ 0x24, 0x00, static_cast<char>(0xbb) };  
  assert(hex2.size() == 3);
  assert(0x24 == static_cast<unsigned char>(hex2[0]));
  assert(0x00 == static_cast<unsigned char>(hex2[1]));
  assert(0xbb == static_cast<unsigned char>(hex2[2]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tanner Sansbury , I have found some articles on using string as you explained and implemented, Thanks you very much its very useful info. Now i am sending "\x24\xbb\xff\x0f\x02\x08\x01\xe0\x01\xe0\x02\x08\x0f\x2d\x0f\x00\x23\x61" and client is able to receive only "\x24\xbb\xff\x0f\x02\x08\x01\xe0\x01\xe0\x02\x08\x0f\x2d\x0f", why is it omitting last 3 Hexadecimal Values. Any idea

Comment: The 3rd to last value is a null character, and the constructor being used by `string` determines length by the first null character.  Either use another constructor ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02f403c9570e1637)) or a different type, such as `vector`.

Comment: Thanks @Tanner Sansbury , Thanks for your great help, now i am sending a hard-coded string via boost server and your solution works perfect, but when it comes to runtime, i am not finding solutions to insert "\x" in-front of each hexadecimal values, so that it can be converted from "2400bb" to "\x24\x00\xbb". i am preferring string because i am using VS2008. Any ideas will help to close this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're sending a wellknown memory trash pattern ([often used: 0xDEADBEEF, 0xBAADF00D, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak)) I'd assume you're reading past the end of a buffer, or perhaps you're dereferencing a stale pointer.

One of the common errors I see people make with ASIO is this:

```
void foo() {
     std::string packet = "hello world";

     boost::asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(packet), my_callback);
}
```

The problem is using a stacklocal buffer with an *asynchronous call*. `async_write` will return immediately, `foo` will return. `packet` is probably gone before the asynchronous operation accesses it.

This is one of the reasons that could lead to you reading the trash pattern instead of your buffer contents, if you're running a debug heap library.

Comment: Thanks @sehe , yes it was sending past the end of a buffer, and there after clients receiving ASCII of each char in array like "32 34 62 62 66 66 30 66 30 32 30 38 30 31 65 30 30 31 65 30 30 32 30 38 30 66 32 64 30 66 30 30 32 33 36 31", so how should i send hex values without converting into ascii, i am not doing any conversion here. should i use different buffers/any data structures???